# How to show 0 axis with chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am using `chartjs` to display some datas but I can't find a way to show a line for 0.

Here is an exemple of chart :

[image]

As you can see, there is no "default line" for the 0 value and I added one in black. Any tips for doing this easily ?

I managed to use `scaleStepWidth` and  `scaleSteps` to have 0 displayed in the scale but the result isn't that good.

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: i think if you use the latest version from github it should be there. I remember seeing a pr for improved negative number handling. Might be the case that it hasn't been merged yet as they are currently doing dev for a  2.0 release which will have an improved scale api. If it isn't there then i have fork with improved negative number handling that is compatible with current version of chartjs https://github.com/leighquince/Chart.js, here is a fiddle showing an example of it http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/gvo0u2oy/

Comment: Yup, this was pain in the *** to do this, so i switched to HighCharts !